# improving my simple python calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

i am rather new at python and this is my very first project i did myself. i am wondering if there is anyway i can improve this or give me advice on making this better. thank you

```py
import sys
valid = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
invalid = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
def start():
    while True:
        a = input("").lower()
        for banned in a:
            if banned in invalid:
                print("error")
            else:
                sum1 = int(a)
        cal = input("")
        b = input("").lower()
        for banned in b:
            if banned in invalid:
                print("Error")
                start()
            else:
                sum2 = int(b)
        break;
    for list in cal:
        if list in valid:
            if list == "+":
                total = sum1 + sum2
                print("=" + total)
            if list == "-":
                total = sum1 - sum2
                print(total)
                start()
            if list == "*":
                total = sum1 * sum2
                print(total)
                start()
            if list == "/":
                total = sum1 / sum2
                print(total)
                start()
        else:
            print("Wrong Format")
            start()
start()
```

Answer (score 3):

A few comments focused less on line-by-line details and more on how to build
better command-line scripts and on simplifying logic.

**How do I use this program**? Your `input()` calls
don't tell me what's going on. Help, please.

**Users don't enjoy tedious interactions with computers**. Would you rather
type a number, press enter, type an operator, press enter, type a number, press
enter ... OR just enter the darn equation? For example:

```
reply = input('Enter equation: INT OP INT: ')
```

**Users really don't enjoy tedious interactions with computers**. With rare
exceptions, sensible command-line programs don't use `input()` at all -- or at
least not by default. Learn about `sys.argv` and let your users run your
calculator directly, without forcing them to become best buddies with their
computer. Here's what a command-line usage might look like:

```
$ python simple-calculator.py 32 + 10
42
```

**Learn about exception handling**. Rather than getting bogged down in creating
a data structure holding every possible bad input (very hard, especially if you
consider all conceivable UTF-8 inputs), just try to do the thing you want to do
-- with a safety net.

```
while True:
    try:
        # Each of these lines could fail. That's OK. Be optimistic!
        s1, op, s2 = reply.split()
        a = int(s1)
        b = int(s2)
        assert op in '+-*/'
        break                  # Success.
    except Exception as e:
        # The safety net.
        print('Invalid input')
```

**Use data structures to simplify logic**. Wouldn't it be cool to get rid of a
pile of `if-else` checks and instead just do the thing you want to do directly?
In such situations, a data structure can often help. What we need is a way to
take an operator and then use it to get a 2-argument function that will perform
the math we need. In other words, we need a mapping between operators and the
corresponding math functions. Here are 3 ways to achieve that:

```
import operator

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

ops = {
    '+': add,                    # Define your own functions.
    '-': lambda a, b: a - b,     # Or lambdas.
    '*': operator.mul,           # Or get them from a library.
    '/': operator.truediv,
}

# With that data structure, our code would reduce to this.
answer = ops[op](a, b)     # Wrap in try-except to catch divide by 0.
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion 1**

Your list of invalid characters and `in` checks will work just as well as a string, but be shorter and more readable.

```
invalid = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Same applies to the `valid` array of characters.

**Suggestion 2**

```
for banned in a:
```

`banned` is a very confusing variable name for this use. You don't know if it's banned until you've compared it with the `invalid` list of characters. You should rather use `character` or `letter` or a shorter basic name like `c` or `x`.

**Suggestion 3**

```
a = input("").lower()
```

`a` is also a poor name here since it doesn't tell us what it is. Rather name it `input1` or something similar, and of course change `b` to `input2` or something else that is descriptive.

**Suggestion 4**

```
for list in cal:
```

`list` is not just a poorly chosen name that misleads the reader, it's also a keyword / function in Python and should not be used as a variable name in any situation. I suggest `operator` as a better name since you're taking in an operator for your calculation.

**Suggestion 5**

You're calling `start()` after every operation except `+` . This looks like a mistake. Why not for `+`?

**Suggestion 6**

```
total = sum1 * sum2
print(total)
```

For every operation, you're saving the total in a new variable and then printing it. But you don't use it for anything else than printing, so you might as well print the result directly without storing it in a variable.

```
print(sum1 * sum2)
```